# Magento performance went dow by 50% after upgrading from 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: magento2, performance, magento-upgrade

I've upgraded Magento 2.1.11 to Magento 2.2.6 and after the upgrade the CPU utilization and CPU load duplicated. Is was a simple and straight forward upgrade.

No server changes were made regarding software or hardware. No PHP upgrade, MySQL, disk, memory, nothing.

No changes were made to any Magento setting.

I have no idea what could have happened. The number of visitors stayed the same, visit hours, etc. No changes there.

All caches are enabled, redis is working as expected... What could I possibly be missing?

[image: CPU Utilization]

[image: CPU Load]

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: How is your Magento performance today?  My offer of Dec 15, 18 is still available to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible that there were no changes or configurations made during upgrade. The thing is that smth is not compatible with your new version: it can be a module/extension, parts of custom code from Magento 2.1, or technologies used in 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 2.2 is slower is because more stuff is bundled with it. And unfortunately in my experience 2.3 is slower than 2.2. (I'd be interested to hear from someone that can prove me wrong).

I'm talking about general speed and not improvements made with bug fixes or rewrites on certain features.

You can remove some features you don't use

https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

Or I recommend using something like new relic to get more of an idea of what is causing load. Then you may be able to pin it on a particular customisation.